# How to use truffle-assertions to verify parameters of an emit?

Tags: solidity, truffle, events, truffle-test, truffle-assertions

I have not been able to find any resources with usage instruction besides [github](https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-assertions) and [blog post](https://kalis.me/check-events-solidity-smart-contract-test-truffle/) by the author

On github an example is show as such:

```
truffleAssert.eventEmitted(result, 'TestEvent', (ev) => {
    return ev.param1 === 10 && ev.param2 === ev.param3;
});
```

And on the blogpost the syntax is like this:

```
truffleAssert.eventEmitted(tx, 'Play', (ev) => {
    return ev.player === bettingAccount && !ev.betNumber.eq(ev.winningNumber);
});
```

Both of these are rather similar.

This is the emit I am trying to test:

`event Emittest(uint date, address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);`

My issues is that if I try to run the same format:

```
let emittest = await contract.function(accounts[1], 66500000,{from: accounts[0]});

truffleAssert.eventEmitted(emittest, 'Emittest', (ev) => {
        return ev.value == set_value;
});
```

It fails with the error `AssertionError: Event filter for Transfer returned no results`. I can extract the correct value by changing the code to:

```
truffleAssert.eventEmitted(emittest, 'Emittest', (ev) => {
        return ev.value.words[0] == set_value;
});
```

As the tokens is of the following structure:

```
value ==== BN {
  negative: 0,
  words: [ 60475904, 14, <1 empty item> ],
  length: 2,
  red: null
}
```

Accessing `.words[0]` doesn't seem like the correct way as it makes it much more difficult to check BigNumbers which are split across multiple indices of the array `words:` without writing a helper function. Addresses extracted from the emit appear and can be accessed as expected.
Splitting between multiple `words` happens much sooner than the 2^53 limit of javascript at around 66 million. I am new to javascript, and might be doing multiple things wrong. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems is that you cannot compare objects with `==` (since numeric values in javascript do not have enough precision they are wrapped in an BN object).

So you have to use the methods provided by the BN library

```
return !ev.value.eq(tokens_sent);
```

The BN library has several methods besides `.eq()` take a look at their [documentation](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/#utilities).

For backward compatibility Truffle also supports [BigNumber](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/#features) library, if for some strange reason BN's methods fail try with BigNumber's methods instead.